# tensor product of a vector space and finite field

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields, tensor-products

I want to know how we can interpret and define the tensor product of V as a vector space with a F as a finite field?

Comment: You mean define $V\otimes F$? What field is $V$ over? And what do you want to tensor over?

Comment: yes,and V is over GF(2), and F is a field extension.

Comment: Then $V\otimes F$ is just the vectorspace over $F$ of same dimension as $V$ is over $GF(2)$.

Comment: how are the elements of V⊗F? may you please give some comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any field $K$ and $K$ vector space $V$, we have that $V\cong V\otimes_K K$ via the mapping $v\mapsto v\otimes 1$.

This mapping is made possible because all of the elements of $V\otimes_K K$ can be written as $x\otimes 1$. You get that $v\otimes f=vf\otimes 1$ for any simple tensor, and then for a general element $\sum \alpha_i(v_i\otimes \beta_i)=\sum (\alpha_i\beta_i v_i\otimes 1 )=\sum (\alpha_i\beta_i v_i)\otimes 1$.

More generally, $V\otimes_K K^n\cong V^n$. In particular, if $F$ is a finite dimensional extension of $K$, you know that $F\cong K^t$ for some positive integer $t$, and then

$V\otimes_K F\cong V\otimes_K K^t\cong V^t$

Comment: V and F are considered as vector spaces and the tensor product of them is as well. how the tensor product of them defined?

Comment: @user118746 The same was as with any two vector spaces. Loosely speaking, you start with the symbols $\{v\otimes f\mid v\in V,f\in F\}$ and use them to span an $F$-vector space: that vector space is $V\otimes_F F$. If you fix a basis for $V$, say $b_1,\dots b_n$, then $b_i\otimes 1$ forms a basis for this vector space.

Comment: I think this can be pretty confusing reading the OP's first comment below his own question: $\;V,F\;$ are vector spaces...over **what** field? Clearly, over some subfield of $\;K\le F\;$, so then the tensor product is apparently $\;V\otimes_K F\;$ , which already isn't the same as written here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, yeah I didn't notice that. I will have to adjust notation.